# formatting one .xlsx into another using C#

Tags: c#, excel

**We generate a report in a particular structure with .xlsx extension.**

> Application Field Detail: Control Procedures
>   System Name: DPE Archer GRC  Version: 6.1.00201.1002
>   Tuesday, October 10, 2017
>   Application Name:   Control Procedures
>   Description:    sss
>   Status: Production
>   Application Owner(s):   "CM: Admin
>   PM: Admin"
>   Field Calculation Order:    ssss
>   Recalculation Schedule: 0 Days
>   Application Fields
>   General:    Field Name: Procedure ID
>       Alias:  Procedure_ID
>       Field ID:   {426748AB-F600-4930-9CBE-AC176F9924FD}
>       Field Type: Tracking ID
>       Status: Active
>       Description:    "This field is automatically populated with a value that 
>   uniquely identifies the record across all applications within 
>   the system."
>       Display Control:    Read Only
>       Field Permissions:  Public
>   Options:    Search Results: Yes     Search Default: Yes
>       Key:    No
>   Configuration Attributes:   ID Type:    System ID
>       Prefix:
>       Suffix:
>   Help Text:  Text:   "This field displays a value that uniquely identifies the record 
>   across all applications within the system."
>       View Display:   Tooltip
>       Edit Display:   Tooltip
>   General:    Field Name: Last Updated
>       Alias:  Last_Updated
>       Field ID:   {FD766D6A-7EB3-462B-B32B-F81612504336}
>       Field Type: Last Updated Date
>       Status: Active
>       Description:    "This field is automatically populated with the date the record 
>   was last updated."
>       Display Control:    Read Only
>       Field Permissions:  Public
>   Options:    Search Results: Yes     Search Default: No
>       Include Time:   Yes     Include User:   Yes
>       Header Display: Yes
>   Help Text:  Text:   This field displays the date the record was last updated.
>       View Display:   Tooltip
>       Edit Display:   Tooltip

**I would like to convert that into the following structure in .xlsx extension.**

> Application/Questionnaire Field Name  Field Alias Field ID    Status  Level   Field Type  Description Help Text   Required?   Calculated Field?
>   Control Procedures  Procedure ID    Procedure_ID    {426748AB-F600-4930-9CBE-AC176F9924FD}          Tracking ID "This field is automatically populated with a value that 
>   uniquely identifies the record across all applications within 
>   the system."    "This field displays a value that uniquely identifies the record 
>   across all applications within the system."
>   Control Procedures  Last Updated    Last_Updated    {FD766D6A-7EB3-462B-B32B-F81612504336}          Last Updated Date   "This field is automatically populated with the date the record 
>   was last updated."  This field displays the date the record was last updated.
>   Control Procedures  Description Description {8AAB3C20-FE24-40BE-B5D6-90F32C2B8767}          Text    This field is used to describe the control activity.    Enter a detailed description of the control activity.       No
>   Control Procedures  Control Placement   Control_Placement   {0BC9C8A6-D992-4A3A-801D-2D10E081C13E}          Values List "This field indicates whether the control is preventive or 
>   detective. For definitions, see the field-level help text." "Select whether the control is preventive or detective 
>   according to the following definitions:"

I am using C#. Could i get some help on the logic?

Answer (score 0):

You mean you wanted to put the header by column? like this:

- |Application Field Detail|System Name|
- |------------------------|-----------|
- |Control Procedures      |DPEArcher GRC Version: 6.1.00201.1002|

Then you should modify your system that generate that excel by putting those header in column. like aplication field detail in Cell A1 and System Name in Cell B2.